# Finding missing probabilities for formal proofs

Tags: provable-security

In formal proofs, you often need to use probabilities to show that the Advantage of an algorithm is negligible. In proofs by contradiction, these probabilities are often tied to probabilities of other, hypothetical algorithms. However, you may end up in situations where you need probabilities that you cannot simply infer. How can you continue the proof at this point?

As an example, let's say I want to proove a specific unlinkability property of a random oracle by contradiction. The basic scheme would be (very informally):

Assume the output of querying a random oracle $h$ with two successive numbers, $x_1=h(n)$ and $x_2=h(n+1)$, was not unlinkable. This implies a PPT algorithm A that links $x_1$ and $x_2$ with non-negligible advantage $Adv_A$, returning $1$ if the values are the result of querying a random oracle with successive numbers, and $0$ otherwise. We use this to construct a Distinguisher $D$ that distinguishes $O$ from true randomness.

We define $O$ to be an Oracle with a hidden variable $b \in \{0,1\}$, which determines if $O$ uses $h$ ($b=1$) or returns truly random data ($b=0$). $D$ can query $O$  polynomially often and tries to determine if $b=1$ or $b=0$.

The distinguisher $D$ could now pick an $n$ and query the Oracle to receive $x_1 = O(n)$, $x_2 = O(n+1)$. He could then run $A$ on these results. If $A$ returns $1$, he outputs the guess $b=1$, otherwise $b=0$.

The probability that $D$ is correct if $b=1$ depends directly on $Adv_A$:

$$Pr[D(O)=1\ |\ b=1] = 0.5 + Adv_A/2$$
$$Pr[D(O)=0\ |\ b=1] = 0.5 - Adv_A/2$$

However, what happens if $b=0$? We don't have any information on how our hypothetical $A$ performs on truly random data, so we cannot determine the probability that it gives the "correct" result (by claiming that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not the result of querying successive numbers). How would be determine, for example, $Pr[D(O)=0\ |\ b=0]$, which we need to compute the non-negligible Advantage of $D$ (and thereby show the contradiction with the assumption that $h$ is a random oracle, since those are indistinguishable from truly random data)?

(The same question crops up for other proofs, I'm just using random oracles for illustration.)